# Is it possible to dynamically map tables to Entity Framework core or any other ORM

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core

The company I work for is researching new possibilities for applications that we can develop, one of the things we would like to do, is be able to dynamically map tables in Entity Framework Core, or any other ORM if Entity Framework Core does not have this possibility.

Let's say we develop an application that we distribute to multiple customers, one of those customers mentioned that they want to have a new entity with certain fields, we update their database to include this model/table, but rather than updating the application to include this new model, is it possible in some way to have Entity Framework Core dynamically map this table?

So far I've searched around on google, but most of the questions I have found are about a model with a different table name, but having the same fields.

Comment: How will your application use the new fields, if you do not update the app??

Comment: Maintaining multiple version of any system to multiple customers is fraught with issues. Generally, the DBSet within the C# is fixed as a model that maps between the table and your classes. If you want a purely dynamic model you can use SQL Readers and Writers and manage the classes and mappings yourself. There are also auto-mappers out there that may also work for you https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-efficient-database-queries-using-entity-framework-core-and-automapper/

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I get the feeling that this isn't a workable scenario. The general idea was to use a generic controller to handle these custom entities so that we can easily add new entities for a customer without having to write an update for the application.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use dot net compiler platform (Roslyn) and then make a program to make the program.